# JPA -> Hibernate not generating automatic id

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an auxiliary standalone application to load the values for entities from some tables, and it is falling because Hibernate is trying to create records without specifying the key value (even if it is specified as `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`).

The bean is:

```
@Entity
public class Location implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  // startRegion attributes
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id = 0;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Location parent = null;

  @Column(nullable=false)
  private boolean active = false;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<Location> divisions = null;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="location", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @MapKey(name="localeId")
  private Map<String, Location_i18n> descriptions = new HashMap<String, Location_i18n>();

  @Column(nullable=true, length=150)
  private String path = null;

  @Column(nullable=true, length=20)
  private String prismaCode = null;

  @Column(nullable=true, length=5)
  private String shortCode = null;
}
```

The SQL shown in Hibernate log is missing the `id` field:

```
insert into Location (active, parent_id, path, prismaCode, shortCode) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

which obviously causes a constraint violation exception.

The relevant properties from `persistence.xml`:

```
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
```

To add to my frustrations, I did a somewhat similar process in a previous process, but I cannot find any difference that is causing the issue.

I have tried both with Hibernate 3.6.10 and 4.1.8 against MS SQL 2008 Express.

Any ideas? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the AUTO strategy, for your database, consists in relying o the database to generate IDs. The ID column of the table should be an auto-increment column, or you should change the ID generation strategy.

Comment: Ok you were right; I was making hibernate generate the tables but somehow the `id` field was not defined as `Identity` in MS SQL. Did drop all the tables and now it works, thanks.

Comment: A tip for those landing here through a Google search for "not generating id"... my symptoms were similar but the root cause was different: Hibernate fails in silent and mysterious ways when the ID column is an Int. Changing the Int to a Long fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

you have created tables manually by entering select query
so hibernate doesn't know the sequence of generation 
create a sequence by name `hibernate_sequence`

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
start with 1
increment by 1
minvalue your_min_value
maxvalue your_max_value
cycle;
```

Answer (score -1):

If your using MsSQL you should place your all annotations above getter method... some times hibernate will ignore the annotations which are defined above variable(Mainly it MsSQL)...